# Custom Painted Controls

Tags: winapi, automated-tests

We need to automate GUI testing of an application developed in Win32 API. Developer's have created this application by custom painted controls. They have controls which look like Grid, Buttons etc., but they are not basic Windows controls.

What is custom painted controls? and how we can test these controls?

Comment: What does this have to do with automated tests?
Is your question actually
1) what is custom painted controls, or
2) how should I test them?

Comment: These questions should be addressed to your developers. They're the ones who know the extent and the nature of their sins.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to them :-(

Answer (score 0):

Test it just like any other UI: Not at all. Move all code out of the callbacks into the application layer where your unit tests can execute them just like any other method.

Rationale: There is little point in testing whether "button.activate()" works; you want to know whether the *your* code behind the button callback works.

If you need to know whether the correct dialogs, etc., are opened, see my blog: [Testing the Impossible: User Dialogs](http://blog.pdark.de/2008/11/11/testing-the-impossible-user-dialogs/)

Answer (score 0):

Have the developers added support for accessibility using [IAccessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/accessibility.iaccessible.aspx)?  If they have, you can use [active accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971310.aspx) to navigate through the controls and test them that way.

If they haven't, open a bug that says that their controls can't be use by disabled people (who need a screen reader or other accessibility aid).

Once they fix that bug, you can use whatever mechanism they added to their controls to allow them to be used by screen readers and other accessibility aids to test their UI.